# How do I getElementById from inside a shadow dom

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

Whenever I try to use `document.getElementById` *inside a shadow dom script tag*, I always get `null`
I looked at questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101967/getelementbyid-from-within-shadow-dom) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520554/custom-element-getrootnode-closest-function-crossing-multiple-parent-shadowd), but none of the answers helped.

Right now I'm using this script, but I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to do this.

```
window.document.body.getElementsByClassName('calculator')[0].getElementsByClassName('content')[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('test')
```

Comment: Actually no, this is the whole purpose of a shadow DOM. It isolates the elements inside it from the real DOM so that selectors of the parent DOM won't return elements inside the shadow DOM. This applies to CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you use selectors inside a shadow DOM. You have to find the `shadowRoot` first, then call `getElementById` from it.

```js
customElements.define("with-shadowroot", class extends HTMLElement {  
    constructor() {
        super()
          .attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
          .innerHTML = `<div><div id="some-div">I'm inside shadowDOM!</div></div>`;
    }
});

console.log(document.getElementById('some-div'));

const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('with-shadowroot');
console.log(divs[0].shadowRoot.getElementById('some-div'));
```

```html
<with-shadowroot></with-shadowroot>
```