# Javascript on click focus latest element with multiple customelements

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have a customelement `WebDesktop` that can create another customelement `AppWindow`.

If I create several `AppWindow` I would like the one I clicked the last to be "focused" when it's created but also that if I click on an already created one it should be focused above the others , it should have a higher z-index.

Is there any way to do this? I don't understand how each already created  `AppWindow` can see how many new elements has been created since it was intially created.

My solution would be to put the zIndex to the amount of current amount of created `AppWindow`
Can each instanced customelement somehow find out how many new elements has been created or something like that? And also keep track if they have been removed?

Comment: Have you tried coding it out yet? Providing code with questions will help the most for giving you better answers.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible in JSfiddle to use classes and I am not allowed to distribute my code.
Imagine 5 custom elements in a shadowdom, they were created by an eventlistener and the first one should be aware if there are new added to them.

I'm sorry I can't provide more resources

Comment: You could try using an array to track the changes, and for determining z-index based on array index. Also, if you can't share your code then you should be consulting the senior or a more senior engineer in your organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some techniques that can help

**Closest element UP the dom**

`let desktop = this.closest('web-desktop')`

This standard method on every element get's you the desktop an AppWindow is in

If your AppWindows have shadowDOM the above method will not work,
as it does **not** "break out" of shadowDOM

To pierce through shadowRoot(s) use `.closestElement()` from:
[Custom Element getRootNode.closest() function crossing multiple (parent) shadowDOM boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520554/custom-element-getrootnode-closest-function-crossing-multiple-parent-shadowd)

**count children**

Once you know the `desktop` your AppWindows are in `desktop.children`
which you can convert to an Array with `[...desktop.children]`

If you have other DOM elements in `.children` your AppWindows are:
  `[...desktop.querySelectorAll('app-window')]`

then `` [...desktop.querySelectorAll('app-window')]`.length `` is your AppWindow count

**going fancy with a live HTMLcollection**

The above get you *static* collections

`desktop.getElementsByTagName('app-window')`

gets you a **live HTMLcollection**, which *can* be helpfull: [When is NodeList live and when is it static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static)

In the Desktop constructor you do:

`this.windows = this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName('app-window')`

and a Getter method in Desktop:

```
get windowcount(){
  return this.windows.length;
}
```

So in an AppWindow constructor you can do:

```
let AppWindowIndex = this.closestElement('web-desktop').windowcount + 1;
```

> disclaimer: all off the top of my head, might have made some syntax errors!

Comment: Hey @Danny '365CSI' Engelman I'm trying to get around detecting an iframe nested within a Shadow DOM element and I seem to be unable to. I have placed a question explaining the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225479/how-to-capture-iframe-nested-within-shadow-doms-shadow-root-open-element I tried your method but somehow it's returning ```null```.