# Style web component within shadow dom, depending on its parent

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component

I am working on a component for uploading files. I have made two web components (wc):

- `wc-uploader` the parent with the select files button.
- `wc-upload` the children that are added to `wc-uploader` as file are added.

If the parent (`wc-uploader`) has the `readonly` or `disabled` attribute, I wish to style the `wc-upload` items differently.

I think the styling should be within the `wc-upload` component as it pertains to it.

This is the selector I tried within the `wc-upload` template but it does not work. I am guess it can't see beyond its shadow root.

```css
wc-uploader[readonly] :host #close {  /* here host = wc-uploader */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

How would one style this element depending on its parent.
E.g. like if a select item is disabled, then it's `option` children are disabled too.

Comment: Do you really need shadowDOM(s)?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes, because I have 3 of these uploaders on the same page, and its quite a lot of Javascript to isolate from each other

Comment: shadowRoots are boundaries. Then the host must do something to let children know attributes changed... emit Event (children listen to) or set attributes on children

Answer (score 1):

For **loose coupling**, so it doesn't matter **when or where** *children* Web Components are attached:

Make the children listen:

```
  this.closest("wc-uploader").addEventListener("close",(evt)=>{
    let parent = evt.detail; //evt.target could do
    if parent.hasAttribute("close") ...
    else ...
  });
```

Then the parent reports its state:

```
attributeChangedCallback(name,oldValue,newValue){
  if(name=="close" || name=="readonly" || name=="disabled"){
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name, {
      bubbles: false, // Event stays at wc-uploader
      detail: this // wc-uploader
    }));
  }
}
```

If your children are deeper down in shadowRoots you need:
[Custom Element getRootNode.closest() function crossing multiple (parent) shadowDOM boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520554/custom-element-getrootnode-closest-function-crossing-multiple-parent-shadowd)

Or use `document.` as your ***"Event Bus"***, but then you have to be careful with your Event-names.

Be aware `addEventListener` attaches a listener **outside** the Web Component scope; so it is not garbage collected when the Component is removed; your task to remove them in the `disconnectedCallback`

Comment: Wow thanks for this indepth answer! You really know web components well. I am still understanding it, but it seems like the way to go.

Comment: I went down the same road learning Web Components; I started 5 years ago...

Comment: Best time to learn web components was 5 years ago, second best time is today =)